# Error: The operator '<' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

> *Error: The operator '<' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '<' operator.

```
title: Text((snapshot.hasData&&snapshot.data !<10)? "${snapshot.data}":'Demo'),
```

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code image?

Comment: Please post at least the whole widget, we cannot suggest something if we don't know the context.

Answer (score 2):

You have to indicate what type the snapshot is, you can do that by indicating it in `<>` at the `StreamBuilder`, like

```
StreamBuilder<int>(
```

Also note that even though

```
snapshot.hasData&&snapshot.data !<10
```

works, it's highly unconventional and you should space it like

```
snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data! < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the length of number of data, it is `snapshot.data!.docs().length < 10`

if its the text value of data,

```
var data = snapshot.data!.doc() as Map<String, dynamic>;
int.tryParse(data['<data_field_for_validation>']) < 10
```